# Sum two counts from 2 different tables in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables on db:

```
1. memberOne

memberName | gender
===================
Jack       | M
Steve      | M
Audrey     | F


2. memberTwo

memberName | gender
===================
Sarah      | F
Steve      | M
Audrey     | F
Alvin      | M
```

I want to display this view:

```
Gender         | Total
=======================
M              | 4
F              | 3
```

I performed this code

```
SELECT t.Gender, COUNT(t.Gender) Total FROM memberOne t
GROUP BY t.Gender
UNION ALL
SELECT d.Gender, COUNT(d.Gender) Total FROM memberTwo d
GROUP BY d.Gender
;
```

And this is what I got:

```
Gender       |  Total
------------- ----------
M                      2 
F                      1 
M                      2 
F                      2
```

How can I sum the total of M and F from each table? Should I use condition to check the gender?
Any helps would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL` and then apply `COUNT`

```
SELECT
    gender as Gender,
    COUNT(*) as Total
FROM
(
    SELECT gender
    FROM memberOne
    UNION ALL
    SELECT gender
    FROM memberTwo
) group by gender
```

Comment: @AkashKC I didn't get you , what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry Ravi, I assumed OP query as subquery in your answer. Your query is right +1.

Comment: Np. I understand.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen We can use order by ;) But, OP didn't mentioned about ordering.

Comment: Oh, actually the order doesn't matter, it's just that I put M first before F for example.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your last query in another query that sums the count of M and F.

```
SELECT
    G, SUM(Total) 
FROM
    (SELECT  
         t.Gender G, COUNT(t.Gender) Total 
     FROM
         memberOne t
     GROUP BY 
         t.Gender

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        d.Gender G, COUNT(d.Gender) Total 
    FROM 
        memberTwo d
    GROUP BY 
        d.Gender) 
GROUP BY 
    gender
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach here would be to union together only the genders from the two tables, and then do a single aggregation to get the male and female counts.

```
SELECT
    gender,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT gender
    FROM memberOne
    UNION ALL
    SELECT gender
    FROM memberTwo
) t
GROUP BY gender
ORDER BY gender DESC
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.Gender, COUNT(n.Gender) Total FROM
(
SELECT t.Gender, COUNT(t.Gender) Total FROM memberOne t
GROUP BY t.Gender
UNION ALL
SELECT d.Gender, COUNT(d.Gender) Total FROM memberTwo d
GROUP BY d.Gender
) n
GROUP BY n.Gender
```

reiterating select and group by after last query

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish your goal working off your initial query would be:

```
select Gender, sum(Total) Total
From (your existing query) q
group by q.Gender
```

A different way would be:

```
select Gender, Count(Gender) Total
from
( select Gender from membeOne
  Union all
  Select Gender from memberTwo ) q
group by q.Gender
```